# why the matrix filter does not work in ie

Tags: internet-explorer, transform

I try to rotate the elment in ie, so I use the matrix filter,html:

```
<div id="car" style="position: absolute; width: 52px; height: 26px; -moz-transform: rotate(45deg); left: 20px; top:206px; z-index: 1000;">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcwtR.png" />
</div>
```

Then add the filter:

```
        var a=document.getElementById("car"),b=45;
        a.style.filter = 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingmethod="auto expand")';
        var e = Math.cos(b * Math.PI / 180),
        c = Math.sin(b * Math.PI / 180),
        g = a.filters.item(0);
        g.M11 = g.M22 = e;
        g.M21 = -c;
        g.M12 = c;
```

Then the div is rotated, but there are a black outline around the image.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mRtQS/)

See this:[image]